# How to ask forgiveness for bad wishes?

Tags: allah

I said every woman should get cheated by their husband. I regret after saying that. If any women gets cheated by their husband will i be responsible?

Answer (score 0):

remember this, Allah is the Most Gracious and the Most Merciful, His mercy encompasses all things, and is the source of all the compassion and mercy that exists. In English the word mercy has several meanings including compassion, forgiveness, kindness, and tenderness. Don’t you ever, EVER give up hope this is shaitans plan go to Allah and repent to him make taubah and Allah will forgive